# Access Music Library from iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

I was trying to create a application in which I need to access Music Library of Iphone Device. Is there any way by which I can access it like UIImageViewController or some thing similar...

Plz help to find out the solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Media Player Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html) gives your application access to the iPod library, letting you find and play audio-based media items.